# How To: AngularJs 'Show All' checkbox to show all rows without paging (toggle)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data table of some 3 or 4 thousand rows, set up with a pager and filtering and such. For most of my users, this is optimum, but a few of them have decided they'd love to have an option to say "Show me all the records, no paging".

So I thought I'd give them a checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chbShowAll" ng-model="vm.ShowAll" ng-change="vm.ShowAllToggle()" /> Show All Results on One Page
        <span ng-if="vm.showingAll"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg" title="Refreshing Results..."></i></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And that checkbox fires off a method that flips my page size from 25 (the default) to the size of the results returned. I've added an ng-if to the pagination so it hides when this checkbox is checked.

```
vm.ShowAllToggle = (
    function() {
        var showAll = vm.ShowAll;
        vm.showingAll = true;

        if (hasValue(showAll) &&
            showAll) {
            vm.currentPage = 1;
            vm.pageSize    = vm.MyCustomers.length;
        } else {
            vm.currentPage = 1;
            vm.pageSize    = 25;
        }

        vm.showingAll = false;
    }
);
```

Now, this all works, but with larger sets of records I want to display a spinner so the user knows "This might take a second".

Instead what I'm getting is that the browser locks up until the page has repainted the larger grid.

So, how can I get this to run a spinner (running off the true/false of `vm.showingAll`), and a bonus of not locking the browser (though I'm willing to have the spinner be a "loading modal" to grey out the window until it's repainted)?

Comment: Try Processing event - fired when DataTables is processing data. https://datatables.net/reference/event/processing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) module. Add the module as a dependency, then add this code in your html:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chbShowAll" ng-model="vm.ShowAll" ng-change="vm.ShowAllToggle()" /> Show All Results on One Page            
    </label>
</div>
<span spinner-on="vm.ShowingAll"></span>
<div ng-if="!vm.ShowingAll">
    <!-- Your data table goes here -->
</div>
```

Additionally, you can customize your spinner to your need!